# How to read a file from a remote device from C program and Ubuntu OS?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, ssh

I am trying to read a file located at remote device, it has Debian OS. 
My C program is running on Ubuntu with Eclipse. The two devices are linked by USB cable. I can access the remote device using ssh from my console like `ssh root@192.168.7.2`.
Now is I like to have access to a file at root of the remote device from my C program. I tried as `FILE *ptr = popen("ssh root@192.168.170.155:/1.jpg", "r");`. It doesn't work. 
What is the correct way to have file access so that I can read file from my C program? Or is there any better approach for that?
Thanks

Comment: `FILE *ptr = popen("ssh root@192.168.170.155 cat /1.jpg", "r");`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid it's not as simple as that. The unix `file` and `pipe` API are meant for working with local files - ie. files that can be accessed by the instance of OS running. In order to read file on remote machine - that's accessible via ssh, is considerably more involved. Normally - the choices are

1. Running an NFS - where remote machine is an NFS server and your machine as NFS client and then you can do normal, `open`, `read`, `write` on your local machine.
2. Other option is to programmatically implement what `ssh` or other protocols do. Slightly more involved. So that option is not available.

Depending upon what you want to do with file, there might be a third option - which is running an `scp` in `system` function in your c program and then copy the file locally and do whatever you want to do with the file.

These are broadly the options. If you can specifically tell - 'what you want to do with the file data', may be there's another option available.

Comment: popening an ssh works fine.

Comment: thanks, yes your discussion is very effective. May I know how to run scp command from my C program? Thanks. I'll look into NFS approach. I like to read jpg file form the remote device for my processing.

Comment: @AhmedMasud: for me, it does not work, what could be wrong? What I mean it doesn't work is even the file is not there, I check FILE with if(ptr != NULL), it is always true. Say remote device doesn't have 2.jpg, but I try to read 2.jpg and if(ptr!=NULL) is always true.

Comment: Of course - you can read that as a popen. Here instead of 'ssh' you can do 'scp', but that's going to throw you all of `stdout` and I am understanding @batuman is interested in reading a file and not `stdout` of an `scp` command or `ssh` command. Not to mention other complications like having to enter a password.

Comment: `man system`. But again that's likely to be a bit complicated - where you might have to pass password as an input.

Comment: As @AhmedMasud says, `popen` can work, but you need to update the invoked command so that it emits output to stdout that can then be read. For example: `FILE *ptr = popen("ssh root@192.168.170.155 cat /1.jpg", "r");` and you would then then be able to read (via fread, perhaps) the contents of that remote file.

Comment: Thanks all. Now I can copy and I can read. The commands from my program are *ptr = popen("scp root@192.168.7.2:/1.jpg /home/1.jpg", "r"); and *ptr = popen("ssh root@192.168.7.2 cat /1.jpg", "r");